# WebGL pie chart - Different results at different Chrome versions

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, opengl-es, webgl, pie-chart

I am trying to develop a pie chart using WebGL. However, I am getting some issues on different Chrome versions. 
On version **40.0.2214.111**, the pie chart looks exactly as I expected with five different parts.

But when I pass to version **43.0.2357.130** the colors on my second and fourth quadrant aren't the same, with the black and brown colors being changed by blue. You can get an example [here](http://bfrgoncalves.github.io/Learning-WebGL/10-testCircles.html) to test it.

Any ideas why this is happening?

**Vertex Shader**

```
attribute vec2 aVertexPosition; 
    varying vec2 vTexCoord; 
    void main(){
        vTexCoord = aVertexPosition;
        gl_Position = vec4(aVertexPosition, 0, 1);
    }
```

**Fragment Shader**

```
precision mediump float;
    varying vec2 vTexCoord; 
    uniform int unumberOfParts;
    void main(){

        vec4 angles = vec4(100.0, 110.0, 70.0, 30.0);
        float prevAngle = radians(0.0);
        float radQuad = radians(90.0);
        float totalAngles = 0.0;

        bool found = false;
        bool hasRest = false;
        float rad = 0.0;
        float AngleToUse = 0.0;
        float rest;

        if (vTexCoord.y < 0.0 && vTexCoord.x < 0.0){ //Checks the coordinates of each quadrant
            for (int i = 0; i<4;i++){
                totalAngles = totalAngles + angles[i];
                if (totalAngles > 90.0){
                    rest = totalAngles - 90.0;
                    AngleToUse = angles[i] - rest;
                    hasRest = true;
                }
                else{
                    AngleToUse = angles[i];
                }
                rad = radians(AngleToUse);
                if ((tan(rad + prevAngle) >= (vTexCoord.y) / (vTexCoord.x)) && (tan(prevAngle) <= (vTexCoord.y) / (vTexCoord.x))){
                    float color = float(i) * 0.3;
                    if ((vTexCoord.x) * (vTexCoord.x) + (vTexCoord.y) * (vTexCoord.y) < 1.0){

                                    gl_FragColor = vec4(color, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
                                    found = true;

                    }   
                }
                prevAngle = prevAngle + rad;
                if (totalAngles > 90.0){
                    break;
                }
            }

        }

        if (vTexCoord.y < 0.0 && vTexCoord.x > 0.0){
            for (int i = 0; i<4;i++){
                totalAngles = totalAngles + angles[i];
                if (totalAngles >= 90.0){
                    if (totalAngles - angles[i] < 90.0){
                        AngleToUse = totalAngles - 90.0;
                    }
                    else if (totalAngles > 180.0){
                        rest = totalAngles - 180.0;
                        AngleToUse = angles[i] - rest;
                        hasRest = true;
                    }
                    else{
                        AngleToUse = angles[i];
                    }

                    rad = radians(AngleToUse);
                     if ((tan(radQuad - (rad + prevAngle)) <= (vTexCoord.y) / -(vTexCoord.x)) && (tan(radQuad - (prevAngle)) >= (vTexCoord.y) / -(vTexCoord.x))){
                        float color = float(i) * 0.3;
                        if ((vTexCoord.x) * (vTexCoord.x) + (vTexCoord.y) * (vTexCoord.y) < 1.0){
                            //gl_FragColor = vec4(1, 0, 0, 1);

                                        gl_FragColor = vec4(color, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
                                        found = true;

                        }   
                     }
                     prevAngle = prevAngle + rad;
                     if (totalAngles > 180.0){
                        break;
                     }

                } 
            }
        }

         else if (vTexCoord.y > 0.0 && vTexCoord.x > 0.0){
            for (int i = 0; i<4;i++){
                totalAngles = totalAngles + angles[i];
                if (totalAngles >= 180.0){
                    if (totalAngles - angles[i] < 180.0){
                        AngleToUse = totalAngles - 180.0;
                    }
                    else if (totalAngles > 270.0){
                        rest = totalAngles - 270.0;
                        AngleToUse = angles[i] - rest;
                        hasRest = true;
                    }
                    else{
                        AngleToUse = angles[i];
                    }

                    rad = radians(AngleToUse);
                    if ((tan(rad + prevAngle) >= (vTexCoord.y) / (vTexCoord.x)) && (tan(prevAngle) <= (vTexCoord.y) / (vTexCoord.x))){
                        float color = float(i) * 0.3;
                        if ((vTexCoord.x) * (vTexCoord.x) + (vTexCoord.y) * (vTexCoord.y) < 1.0){
                            //gl_FragColor = vec4(1, 0, 0, 1);

                                        gl_FragColor = vec4(color, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
                                        found = true;

                        }   
                    }
                     prevAngle = prevAngle + rad;
                     if (totalAngles > 270.0){
                        break;
                     }

                } 
            }
          }

          else if (vTexCoord.y > 0.0 && vTexCoord.x < 0.0){
            for (int i = 0; i<4;i++){
                totalAngles = totalAngles + angles[i];
                if (totalAngles >= 270.0){
                    if (totalAngles - angles[i] < 270.0){
                        AngleToUse = totalAngles - 270.0;
                    }
                    else{
                        AngleToUse = angles[i];
                    }

                    rad = radians(AngleToUse);
                     if ((tan((rad + prevAngle)) >= -(vTexCoord.x) / (vTexCoord.y)) && (tan((prevAngle)) <= -(vTexCoord.x) / (vTexCoord.y))){
                        float color = float(i) * 0.3;
                        if ((vTexCoord.x) * (vTexCoord.x) + (vTexCoord.y) * (vTexCoord.y) < 1.0){
                            //gl_FragColor = vec4(1, 0, 0, 1);

                                        gl_FragColor = vec4(color, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
                                        found = true;

                        }   
                     }
                     prevAngle = prevAngle + rad;
                     if (totalAngles > 360.0){
                        break;
                     }

                } 
            }
          }



    if (found == false){
        if ((vTexCoord.x) * (vTexCoord.x) + (vTexCoord.y) * (vTexCoord.y) < 1.0){
            gl_FragColor = vec4(0, 0, 1, 1);
        }
        else{
            gl_FragColor = vec4(1, 1, 1, 0);
        }
    }

    }
```

**WebGL**

```
var c = document.getElementById('c');
var gl = c.getContext('experimental-webgl');

var vertexPosBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexPosBuffer); 
var vertices = [-1, -1 , 1, -1, -1, 1 , 1, 1] 
gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array(vertices), gl.STATIC_DRAW); 

vertexPosBuffer.itemSize = 2; 
vertexPosBuffer.numItems = 4;
vertexPosBuffer.numberOfParts = 2;

vs = document.getElementById('vshader').textContent;
fs = document.getElementById('fshader').textContent;

var program = createProgram(vs,fs);
gl.useProgram(program);
program.vertexPosAttrib = gl.getAttribLocation(program,'aVertexPosition');
program.numberOfParts = gl.getUniformLocation(program,'anumberOfParts');
gl.enableVertexAttribArray(program.vertexPosArray);
gl.vertexAttribPointer(program.vertexPosAttrib, vertexPosBuffer.itemSize , gl.FLOAT, false , 0, 0); 
gl.uniform1i(program.numberOfParts, vertexPosBuffer.numberOfParts);

gl.finish();
gl.drawArrays(gl.TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0 , vertexPosBuffer.numItems);
```

Comment: This isn't so much an answer as it is just general advice.  First of all, your shader is so crazy complicated.  With a shader with so many branches, it is likely not much more performant than doing this on the CPU.  Secondly, with such a complicated shader it will be very difficult to debug.  Try writing the same algorithm on the CPU side and see if it it works correctly.  Thirdly, for such a simple output, you could likely achieve the same picture with better performance by just using simple 2D canvas drawing (unless learning OpenGL is your goal with this project).

Comment: @aeskreis my goal with this is to create a pie chart to be placed at node location of a force layout graph with up to 10.000 nodes. I tried using D3 and other libraries but the volume of data was to big to have a dynamic graph. That is why I am using WebGL. I don't know that much about OpenGL but I haven't found anything about creating 2D pie charts so I tried to create mine. Any ideas on how can I simplify my shader?

Comment: One way that I could think of to optimize this greatly would be to draw the pie chart with each section represented as a triangle, with the goal to create a "square" chart.  You would have a position, color, and texture coord as your per vertex data.  Then, you could attach an alpha mask which would give you the circular shape you wanted.  This would also give you some basic antialiasing (assuming your alpha mask is antialiased, this is a simple feature of photoshop or the like).  I can leave an answer with more details if you'd prefer.

Comment: That would be really nice. If you could leave an answer with more detail I I would appreciate.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using something like a spritesheet to solve this problem? First create like 100 different pie charts with different levels of fullness on 2D canvas. Then upload the entire sprite sheet to the GPU. On rendering, just render the sprite (a portion of the spritesheet) with desired level of fullness.

The setup would be something like this:

1) generate all the sprites on the 2D canvas

2) upload canvas to GPU with texImage2D

3) for each sprite, pre-calculate the uv values on the texture.

4) at render time, determine the correct uv values to use, then just render with a standard texture with uv fragment shader.

5) enjoy!